# How restrict the drag element between one boundary in Angular Material 7 CDK?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular7, angular-material-6, angular-dragdrop

For my current project am trying to implement the drag element one position to another position inside one div. For this I am using the Angular Material 7 CDK drag and drop features. it dragging all over the page but want to only drag inside particular div. But I didn't see any option to control the boundary in Angular Material 7 CDK drag and drop.

Can anyone tell me how to control boundary in material or suggestion some other plugins which is compactable for angular 7. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `cdkDragBoundary` which will be useful to prevent the user from being able to drag an element outside of another element.

You can use it as following:

```
<div class="example-boundary">
  <div class="example-box" cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary" cdkDrag>
    I can only be dragged within the dotted container
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about it from here [Angular Material Restricting movement within an element](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#restricting-movement-within-an-element)